# How can you print the specific key pressed to the console in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am stuck on this. I am trying to output the specific key pressed to the console, but at the moment all of the keys pressed output "2". Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

s = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

running = True
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT: #The user closed the window!
            running = False #Stop running
    # Logic goes here

        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(e.type)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the type of event (`KEYDOWN`), so you always get the same output.

The keyboard events `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) create a [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object with additional attributes. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute (e.g. `K_RETURN` , `K_a`) and the `mod` attribute contains a bitset with additional modifiers (e.g. `KMOD_LSHIFT`). The `unicode` attribute provides the Unicode representation of the keyboard input.
A user friendly name of a key can be get by [`pygame.key.name()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name):

```py
running = True
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            
            # print key
            print(e.key)

            # print unicode representation
            print(e.unicode)

            # print user firendly name
            print(pygame.key.name(e.key))
```

Comment: I tried implementing the edited version of the code and that worked, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Krypton200 Nothing has changed. I have only added some options.